# Batch convertion with raw to GeoTIFF images

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, geotiff-tiff, anaconda

I have several 12-bit raw images acquired with Survey3 MAPIR spectral camera. There is a MAPIR Camera Control (MCC) software for make the images batch convertion to GeoTIFF format, but doesn't work very well.

Does anybody know how I could do this convertion in batch, with ANACONDA, QGIS or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit, I modified my answer.

Use this application to convert your RAW images to JPEG or TIFF:
https://github.com/mapircamera/MAPIR_Camera_Control

Then you can continue with GDAL and Python, just run it in QGIS Python Console:

```
import os

path = 'd:/your/jpegfolder/'

logfile = 'd:/what/you/want.log'
filenames = os.listdir (path) # get all files' and folders' names in the current directory

filelist = []
for filename in filenames: # loop through all the files and folders
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path), filename)): # check whether the current object is a folder or not
        filelist.append(os.path.splitext(filename)[0]) # drop extension

commands = []
for filename in filelist:
    command = 'gdal_translate -of GTiff ' filename + '.jpg ' + filename + '.tiff'
    commands.append(command)

for c in commands:
    os.system(c + ' > ' + logfile)
```

Comment: If I change`filename + '.jpg '` to`filename + '.raw '` works to? My goal is the convertion of RAW files.

Comment: Ehh, you modified the question (JPEG to raw) :D. I thought that the images are georeferenced, since you want GeoTiff, which is georeferenced. 
Here is a list about GDAL supported raster formats:
https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html
For georeferencing you have to use the -gcp option.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with python you can use the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

folder_containing_jpegs = "path/to/your/folder/that/contains/jpges"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_containing_jpegs):
    for file in files:
        outfile_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root,file))[0] + ".tiff"
        try:
            jpeg = Image.open(os.path.join(root,name))
            im.save(outfile_name,"TIFF",quality=100)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
```

I used the answer by [Anbarasan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3750901/anbarasan-thangapalam) from [converting tiff to jpeg in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870504/converting-tiff-to-jpeg-in-python) and slightly modified the code. I have not tested it.

Comment: I can test this function of RAW files to?

Answer (score -1):

Total Image Converter supports the widest list of output file types: PDF, TIFF, BMP, PNG, JPEG, JPEG2000, ICO, GIF, TGA, PXM, PS, PCL! Besides, it converts many rare formats like PALM, PICT, XPM, FIX.Get neat PDF documents with all images inside. Comine several image files into one PDF with ease!. TIC uses 2 packers to optimize images. Guetzli works great for photos. But it is slow - about 1 min per photo. If the source is just a screenshot or an icon, TIC uses the MozJpeg packer. It's 10 times faster. The best part is that the app chooses which packer to use itself depending on the source file to save time (Auto mode).

Comment: IMHO, that's not answer the question. Here, it's about geo-images with coordinates data. It's not even an Open Source Software, and TIC is paying. A real answer should contains software like GDAL.